# Linux and Virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

1. I installed 2 OS in my Virtual Machines, one windows and the Other Linux,  even i selected the Bridged network in the Machine setting i can not get my linux Os connected to the Internet!
2. I assigned 2 different Ip addresses to Linux and Windows, both belonging to the same subnet, but i was not able to do a simple ping between these two OS!

All i want to do is to do a simple experimental Nmap from Linux to Windows through linux terminal.

would be great to hear your insights.

Comment: You should try to do things in order: first do default installations and ensure you can get internet accesses through NAT networking. Then (for each virtual machine) add a second interface card in bridged mode (carefully following virtualbox manual) and ensure it works. Only then you should try to have both VM to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try attached image...Hope it will help :)

Check the connect Network adapter option in virtual box setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hope this help. i've got same issue, because i have select wrong NIC.

[image]